# Fixed Header showing when we navigate to different page in single page application

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-ui-router

I'm using Datatables with AngularJS and the FixedHeader plugin which works fine when the table is displayed on the page. My issue is that when I navigate to a different page (single page application) using angular UI router, the FixedHeader header still shows.

Does anybody know why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that is an issue with the [FixedHeader](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) plugin to [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

There is an angular-DataTables module at https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome, which has a page about the plugins that work with it. This page lists the FixedHeader plugin and mentions the same issue you are seeing.

See https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withFixedHeader.

This page says the following:

> Beware when using routers. It seems that the header and footer stay in
>   your DOM even when you change your application state. So you will need
>   to tweak your code to remove them when exiting the state.

It also shows a workaround for angular-ui-router:

```
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  templateUrl: 'somewhereInDaSpace',
  controller: function($scope, title){
    // Do your stuff
  },
  onEnter: function(title){
    // Do your stuff
  },
  onExit: function(){
    // Remove the DataTables FixedHeader plugin's headers and footers
    var fixedHeaderEle = document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader');
    angular.element(fixedHeaderEle).remove();
    var fixedFooterEle = document.getElementsByClassName('fixedFooter');
    angular.element(fixedFooterEle).remove();
  }
});
```